# Wireless_tools- iwconfig wlp5s5 no wireless extension

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, network-interface

I have installed Wireless tools, GNUtls, Openssl, WpaSupplicant, Wget also, but I do not know if I need some library.

```
iwconfig
```

and the others wireless tools do not recognize wireless interface.

I set up interface with

```
ip link set <interface> up
```

i configured it with wpa-supplicant and i'm using textual browser and wget so finally i can download sources directly from BLFS. :)

I made sure that kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT=y`, `CONFIG_WEXT_CORE=y` and `CONFIG_WEXT_PROC=y`. I tried to recompile and reinstall but nothing to do... Wireless Tools is supplied without "Uninstall" script, deleting all files manually it is best solution? Is there an automated method to extract the tree of an installation from a build package?

---

so,

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i net 

lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI     
Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
05:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R [1814:3060]
```

And

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for gaia: 
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 06
   serial: 00:25:22:ad:ac:e4
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:49 ioport:c800(size=256) memory:d3fff000-d3ffffff memory:d3ff8000-d3ffbfff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 5
   bus info: pci@0000:05:05.0
   logical name: wlp5s5
   version: 00
   serial: 80:1f:02:44:a2:29
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.13.3-1 firmware=0.26 ip=192.168.1.76 latency=32 link=yes maxlatency=4 mingnt=2 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:20 memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff
```

I have installed firmware by Ralink, now i' mworking in archlinux and Wireless tools work properly with firmware=0.34 and drivers=3.15.1

Comment: This has nothing to do with wireless tools. It means your wireless interface does not have a suitable driver. To get help, you will have to tell us distro and output of *lspci -vnn | grep -i net* and of *sudo lshw -C network*.

Comment: What do you mean by swittable?

Comment: I mean a driver appropriate for your wifi card

Comment: when i doing iwlist -v it say "Cannot read /proc/net/wireless"

Comment: Not clear: is it working now, or not? If not, what are the symptoms?